# アクセス日数や今日の実績などの「日」に関する区切りをJST 00:00:00にしたほうがよいのでは？

Tags: 機能の要求, 却下

日本語版スタックオーバーフローは、質問者/回答者共にJSTにいる方がほとんどだと思うので、
実績やアクセス日数の基準をJST 00:00:00にしたほうがわかりやすいのでは？

// 今はUTC 00:00:00が１日の始まりですよね？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

最初に英語圏向けだったため、世界の多くの国を存在しているからこそ、UTCを選びました。データベース内
では、全部の計算はUTCを使っています。例えば：１日の信用度制限、バッジのトリッガー、アクセス日数、選挙等。

当サイトだけのアクセス日数をJSTにすると、上記のコードの部分全部触らないと行けません。

開発者に前聞きましたが、半端ない仕事の量になります。この変更を考えても、一つの言語がひとつにタイムゾーンにしか話さない国が非常に少ないです（日本と韓国ぐらい？）ので、仕事の量とネットワークへの重要性を考える上で優先度が高くないと想定できます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ヘルプなどで日の判定がUTCベースである点を紹介しておくと親切なのかも？

Comment: @fkm 喜んで適用します！入れたい文書を教えてくれたら、すぐに適用します。