# モデレーター選挙の正確なスケジュールはどれですか？

Tags: サポート, 選挙

[2022 年モデレーター選挙](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election/1)の立候補の段階が始まりましたが、この立候補の開始時間が 2022-03-15T05:00:00+09:00 頃でした。最初に選挙の開始が[アナウンスされたとき](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3697/19110)には 2022-03-14 から始まるとなっていたので、JST だと思うと少し相違があります。[一番直近のアナウンス](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3708/19110)には日時が書かれていませんでした。

ここからの選挙は、どのような日程で進んでいくのでしょうか？　また、そのスケジュールはどのタイムゾーンで解釈されるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

タイムゾーンについて：
Stack Exchange サイトで使用される日時は **UTC** が用いられています。ですが、日本語版ユーザーの大多数がおそらく JST におられることを考慮すると、UTC だけではなく JST の日時をメタの投稿など編集可能なものについては併せて記述するとクリアになりそうです。

選挙の日程について：
[選挙ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1)　の立候補開始などの文字の右側にカーソルを合わせると[このように](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXGY7.png)グレーで「2022-03-14 20:00:00Z」といった日時が表示されます。選挙の立候補や予備選、投票の開始設定時刻は全て 20:00:00Z UTC で進められているように見えます。

そのため、JNatさんがチャットで紹介された日程の March 7, 14, 21, 29 とは UTC 20時の意味合いのようですので、 JST だと日付変更線を超えるため翌日 8, 15, 22, 30 の 5時となり、日程は以下のようになります。

| JST | 内容 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-08 05:00 | 質問リストの作成 |
| 2022-03-15 05:00 | 立候補開始 |
| 2022-03-22 05:00 | 立候補者数が4人以上10人以下であった場合には投票開始 |
| 2022-03-30 05:00 | 立候補者数が4人以上10人以下であった場合には投票終了 |

*立候補者数が4人未満の場合には、立候補期間が1週間延長され、投票開始及び投票終了日時が1週間のちに続くことになります。*

日本語版では今回が初めての選挙ですので、改善できる点がありましたら早急に編集したいと思います。 具体的な改善案をいただければ本当にありがたいです！

参考：
[アクセス日数や今日の実績などの「日」に関する区切りをJST 00:00:00にしたほうがよいのでは？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1591/14055)

Comment: なるほど。合わせて https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3697/5 のように書き換えました。